# I used phpmailer, it was working only in my gmail account but i tried to use cpanel email(eg:me@domainname.com) it doesn't working

Tags: php, mysql, email

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.domainename.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'info@domainename.com';
$mail->Password = 'password for my email';
$mail->setFrom('info@domainename.com');
$mail->addAddress('me@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'The needed information for next login!';
$mail->Body = 'my message';

//send the message, check for errors
if ($mail->send()) {
  echo"success";
}

?>
```

I used phpmailer, it was working only in my gmail account  but if i tried to use cpanel email(eg:me@domainname.com) it doesn't working till now and i have phpmailer forder.

Comment: change smtp.domainename.com to mail.domainename.com because usually hostings that have Cpanel and etc does default set mail.* subdomain as MX. You can check it by doing this: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3anum8er.me&run=toolpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set smtp host: `mail.domainname.com`

By default most cpanel based hostings set SMTP servers address like `mail.domainname.com` and mostly use the same address in MX record

You can get Your MX record by using this service: [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com)

Remove:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Add:

```
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

debug will verbose the actions, `ErrorInfo` show why it's not sending.

Comment: Check with default SMTP port. 25

Comment: Contact Your hosting provider

Comment: It cannot be! I've just checked Your hosting with: "telnet mail.nsanga.rw 25" it's working. Here is the prove: https://imgur.com/EP7GyJX  Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Jules.S please read carefully. I said to comment (or remove) smtp secure line, and change the port to 25. can You do it?

Comment: @Jules.S Username is 'email' ? or You just changed it to not be seen?

Comment: @ num8er i changed it

Comment: @Jules.S I've just checked Your code on my computer. of course I don't know password for info@nsanga.rw, my was able to connect to mail server successfully, issue was on authentication, so it's normal. see this: https://gist.github.com/num8er/3a21fa6066a39039fbe48bab42112308  so code works. I don't know how You test it, but it works. so let's add me in skype: anarjafarov  and let's debug Your issue on Your side. ok?

Comment: The problem can caused by testing it in localhost??

Comment: @Jules.S can You open putty and connect using telnet option to mail.nsanga.rw  with port 25 ?  also ping mail.nsanga.rw, wanna know if ip addresses are same.